# How can I receive data from GPS device which is sending data to my server ip and port using PHP?

Tags: php, node.js, sockets, gps

I have a GPS device which is sending data to my server `103.209.146.80` and port `5672`

I want to create a php script or a JS script which reads the incoming data on this port.

My first step is to catch the data. I am using this PHP code but it is giving error:

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen("103.209.146.80", 5672, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    fwrite($fp, "You message");
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must first know what type of connection tcp or udp transmits your GPS, then create a socket server (tcp / udp) that listens on the port where you will transmit your GPS.

Do not forget that you must configure a valid APN in your GPS.

Comment: everything is done from the gps end, i sent the data on the servers of the company from whom i purchased , they received it, now i am trying to receive it on my vps server... can u help with some code